# Scan numbers as string

Tags: c, scanf

my input is of form of: `number:number` for example `16:13`
my goal is to take this input and break it to the two numbers.

for example first number is 16, second number is 13.
is there a way to use SCANF to read the numbers directly? or the only was is to use a function to convert the string to numbers after i lose the separator?

i can not change the format of the input.

Comment: Did you take any time at all to [read the documentation for `scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) ?

Comment: I wouldn't use `scanf()`. I'd use `fgets()`, `strchr()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: Use [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the entire string & break it at delimiter `:` using [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
scanf_s("%d:%d", &num1, &num2);
```